# Integral representation of the mean value of the partition function logarithm, i.e., $\langle \log Z \rangle $

Tags: improper-integrals, mathematical-physics, means, statistical-mechanics

I'm reading an old paper and it presents some sort of identity but no reference. It says the following:
*In order to calculate the average of $\log Z$* (here $Z$ is the canonical partition function), *one can use an integral representation of the logarithm:*
\begin{equation}
\langle \log Z \rangle = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}- \langle e^{-tZ} \rangle }{t} dt
\end{equation}
I have no clue on how to prove or, at least, understand this identity.
So please help me understand this.

Comment: The obvious integral representation of the logarithm is $$\log Z = \int_1^Z t^{-1} dt$$. Perhaps you can get this identity from a change of variables?

Comment: No. I think I found the answer. That identity is obtained by the contour integral
\begin{equation}
\oint dt \frac{e^{-t}}{t}
\end{equation}
where the contour is taken first in the real axis from $\epsilon$ to $R$, then an arc going from $0$ to $\pi/2$, then in the imaginary axis from $R$ to $\epsilon$ and finally an arc from $\pi/2$ to $0$. Then, when taken the limits $R \rightarrow \infty$ and $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ the 1st and 3rd integral give the RHS of the identity while the 2nd integral vanish and the 4th yields the LHS, with $Z=\imath$ and no brackets.

Comment: Browsing Wikipedia today, I noticed that this integral representation (without a contour integral) is actually included at the end of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Integral_representation_of_the_natural_logarithm) section.